# square digit chains project euler

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do problem 92 in project euler, https://projecteuler.net/problem=92

my code is:

```
a = input('number: ')

loop = False

while loop==False:
    list(str(a))
    x = [int(i) for i in a]
    b = []
    c = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        b.append((x[i]**2))
    d = sum(b)
    #print(d)
    if d not in c:
        c.append(d)
    else:
        loop = True
    a = d

print (c)
```

(I don't know why it is formatting weird, sorry i'm a beginner at this stuff)
it is giving me an error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" on line 6. I don't understand. help?

Comment: There's a ton of things wrong with this. `list(str(a))` does nothing. All your variables are going to be reset every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Basically your `a` variable is an Integer and you cant iterate over integers.
All you have to do is turn `a` into a string like this

```
a = str(a)
```